# Forward and Reverse Field Relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many, relationship

The ***context*** is: I have a Match model where I want to store data for a football match. There are some fields are going to be common to all matches (not the value I mean the field name), such as season, local_team, away_team... But the stats of the match are going to differ (one match can have 2 goals and another one 0).

***My approach*** to building a common abstract (Django model) of Match is creating the class Stats (to store the actions) and the Class Action. So:

Action will have fields --> minute, player, action(goal, red card...)

Stats will have fields --> actions (Many to many field to store several actions)

Match will have fields --> local, away, ref, stadium, stats (so all matches have 1 common field which is stats).

The ***big question comes now***, when I would like to give a proper name to actions and stats. Because a lot of actions and stats from different matches are going to be stored together, when de MatchAdminForm ask me for the stats of the game I want to know quickly which one corresponds, same when the StatsAdminForm ask me for the actions.

The ideal for stats would be to catch the name of the local_team of the match which this stats belongs to. **`How can I access to that name if Match has not been created yet??`** (Same parallelism with actions and stats)

Here I share my models.py so you can check.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from globalModels.models import Season
from seasonalModels.models import SeasonTeam as Team
from seasonalModels.models import SeasonPlayer as Player
from seasonalModels.models import SeasonReferee as Referee
from seasonalModels.models import SeasonStadium as Stadium


class Action(models.Model):

    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        ('Gol', 'Gol'),
        ('Yellow', 'Yellow Card'),
        ('2Yellow', 'Second Yellow Card'),
        ('Red', 'Red Card'),
    )

    # minute = models.IntegerField(choices = (range(1,90)))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='abc')
    minute = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player_action')
    action = models.CharField(choices=ACTION_CHOICES, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):

        return "%s %s %s" % (Match.local_team, Match.away_team) # Ideally I will like the stat to give this information BUT MATCH DOESN'T EXISTE YET error


class Stats(models.Model):

    actions = models.ManyToManyField(Action, related_name='action_name')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='auto')

    def __str__(self):

        return "%s %s %s" % (Match.local_team, Match.away_team) # Ideally I will like the stat to give this information BUT MATCH DOESN'T EXISTE YET error


class Match(models.Model):

    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_season')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # round = models.IntegerField(choices = (range(1,10)))
    round = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=True)

    local_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_local_team')
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_away_team')
    referee = models.ForeignKey(Referee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_referee')
    stadium = models.ForeignKey(Stadium, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_stadium')

    local_team_possession = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    away_team_possession = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    stats = models.OneToOneField(Stats, blank=True, related_name='match_stats')

    local_team_goals = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    away_team_goals = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    local_team_yellow_cards = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    local_team_red_cards = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    away_team_yellow_cards = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    away_team_red_cards = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Summarizing, when I am in the admin browser API and select ADD MATCH
In the stats field, I am able to ADD STATS (that **are going to be stored in the corresponding match, but I would like to save a customized fieldname** for the name field for stats, as well as the second case).

Thanks a lot in advance guys!

PR

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `related_name` to trace back through your specific `instance`. For example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s %s" % (Match.local_team, Match.away_team)
```

^ That refers to the `Match` **class**, not an **instance**.

Instead, you can use:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{0} {1}".format(self.match_stats.local_team, self.match_stats.away_team)
```

Comment: Hi @Hybrid thanks for replying!
This is reasing a error in the relationship:


        'Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
        Exception Value: Stats has no match_stats.`